# Diagnosing occasional HTTP 5xx errors in Elastic Beanstalk and Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

My monitoring tab in Elastic Beanstalk is showing occasional HTTP 5xx errors, both from the EB instance and the ELB that performs its load balancing.

The trouble is that I generally only see these a few hours after they occur, and by the time I log into the EB instance the logs have rotated and see no trace of the error.

What's the best way to record the request and response associated with these errors for later viewing?

Answer (score 0):

Best and cheap option to achieve this is set up a cron job on the EC2 instance  that will move the logs to a AWS S3 bucket each 15 min or so. Or in other word store the logs in AWS S3 so you can analyze them when ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things I've found out in the past few weeks (I'll maybe edit into a more coherent answer later):

- Consider the layering here: we've got ELB -> httpd -> Tomcat (in my example). I'd forgotten about httpd (Apache 2.2 atm)
- You can enable ELB logging into an S3 bucket of your choice. This allows you to see the results returned to the client
- From there, trace through to httpd to see if there are any errors in `/var/log/httpd`
- And then from there, trace through to the Tomcat logs to see if the same errors pop up there
- I was seeing errors in ELB and httpd that weren't showing in Tomcat
- I was also seeing a number of error messages similar to:

->

```
"proxy: error reading status line from remote server"
"(103)Software caused connection abort: proxy: pass request body failed"
```

Reading around, these may be caused by bugs in `mod_proxy`.